# Rendering with swf files sometimes causes skipping frames

Tags: premiere, editing, adobe, adobe-media-encoder, flash

I mostly create simple infographic style animaitons with Flash then import them to Premiere to adjust timing and add extra effects.I know it is not a pro. way to work but it reduces rendering and esportting time for me. and i have to watch every movie i made from beginning to end many time.. With 4 eyes without any blink not to skip this error.

From time to time i had this issue when i export movie final movie has skipping repeating frames and even sometimes distorted green lines occur.
And the worst thing is that it happens randomly (or atleast not in a pattern so that i can say the cause)

I tried lots of export ways but it mostly happens..

Things i can count are..

1. Lower resolutions are fine almost nothing like this happens.
2. 1280 and 1920 %80-90 it happens at some point.
3. Exporting mov seems like a solution but both then i have to convert again for mp4

**Possible causes i can think of but cannot prove are.**

Frame server might mix because of st. while serving swf frames to premiere.

Another software during render (st. like watching youtube or continuing editing with another soft like after effects, premiere, proshow or even flash) working background might cause this.

My graphic card might cause this.

My harddisk can cause this while writimng file to disk. (Not so sure because i also tried exporting to SSD system harddisk but again it happens)

**Solutions i could find**

1-Export as uncompressed mov then convert to mp4. Which both takes my extra time and disk space..

Intel Xeon 3.5 GHZ
32 GB ram
Win 10 64 bit
Dell precision T1700 workstation
SSD hard disk for system and softwares
1 tb internal Normal harddisk for workspace

Any idea is appriciated.. 
Thanx for all the help

Comment: This should be reported as bug: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/878528 (IMO).